# Ambiguous column name 'poid'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

The query is fine before joining table, but after joining patientinfo table to get the patid, it shows Ambiguous column name 'poid', would anyone help me with this?

```
SELECT [ProDbArchive].[dbo].[t_structuredNotes].[noteName] 
       ,[ProDbArchive].[dbo].[t_structuredNotes].[poid] 
       ,[ProDbArchive].[dbo].[t_Patientinfo].[patid] 
       ,CAST ([ProDbArchive].[dbo].fn_tstampint([statedNoteTS]+[ProDbArchive].[dbo].fn_offset(poid)) As DATETIME  )As StatedNoteTime
       ,[ProDbArchive].[dbo].[t_structuredNotes].[noteType]
       ,[ProDbArchive].[dbo].[t_structuredNotes].[noteText]

  FROM [ProDbArchive].[dbo].[t_structuredNotes]
 INNER JOIN [ProDbArchive].[dbo].[t_Patientinfo] ON [ProDbArchive].[dbo].[t_structuredNotes].[poid]= [ProDbArchive].[dbo].[t_Patientinfo].[poid]
  where noteType = 'Procedure' 
  and noteName = 'Bedside Tracheostomy'
  and CAST ([ProDbArchive].[dbo].fn_tstampint([statedNoteTS]+[ProDbArchive].[dbo].fn_offset(poid)) As DATETIME  ) > '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
  and CAST ([ProDbArchive].[dbo].fn_tstampint([statedNoteTS]+[ProDbArchive].[dbo].fn_offset(poid)) As DATETIME  ) < '2017-08-01 00:00:00.000' 
order by statedNoteTS asc
```

Answer (score 3):

Both your `t_structuredNotes` and `t_Patientinfo` tables have a `poid` column, so when you try to reference it without a table name (e.g., in `fn_offset(poid)`), you get an error about the column being ambiguous, as the database cannot know which one you mean.

Since their values should be equal anyway (as per your join condition), just choose one and specify it in a fully qualified manner. E.g.:

```
fn_offset([ProDbArchive].[dbo].[t_structuredNotes].[poid])
```

Comment: I'd also recommend introducing aliases to cut down on the amount of clutter throughout the query.

Comment: thank you very much expert Mureinik,  it is working now!